# Docker Watchtower gives me an error: port is missing" providerName=docker

Tags: docker, docker-watchtower, watchtower

```sh
today at 15:09  time="2021-01-15T14:09:47Z" level=error msg="service \"watchtower-source\" error: port is missing" providerName=docker container=watchtower-source-338c650e497d25342cd554c2dcddda597a8ae1f6f1af9d38ddffa4768d51c512
```

... but there isn't a port to expose
what am I missing? any pointers?

#### My `docker-compose.yml` config for `watchtower`

```yaml
  watchtower:
    image: v2tec/watchtower:latest
    container_name: watchtower
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --interval 120
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.watchtower.tls=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks related to Traefik, not wotchtower.

For instance, you see the same error in [traefik/traefik issue 5418](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/5418):

> When you enable the "file provider", it means you are enabling the dynamic configuration to be retrieved from a file, while `traefik.yml` is the file containing the static configuration.
> Reference: https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/getting-started/configuration-overview/#the-static-configuration.

Similar to [`traefik/traefik` issue 5732](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/5732#issuecomment-552087308)

> Just needed to add this line to service:
>
> ```
> - traefik.http.services.whoami5.loadbalancer.server.port=80
> ```

Try to define routers and services in the file specified by providers.file.filename a